# opencart - php Create an excel file with order details and send it by email

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

CMS: Opencart

Language: PHP

Web site type: e-commerce with online payments and products

Problem: On customer ordering a product, the excel sheet should be generated and send over email to a delivery company and store owner

What I have accomplished: I have written the code for generating the excel sheet and saving it on the server, the link to a excel sheet will then be sent by email. I have found also the file on server that is responsible for the action that proceeds the order.

Code for creating an excel sheet:

```
  <?php
        $data = array(
            array("ORDER ID" => "here will be order id", "COMPANY NAME" => "name of the store", "ADDRESS LINE1" => "address of the customer", "ADDRESS LINE2" => "2nd address if filled","CONTACT PERSON"=>"Name of the customer","CITY" =>"City customer lives in", "PHONE_1"=>"phone","CONTENT" =>"a product name", "WH NUMBER" =>"the model number of product","PIECES"=>" amount ","COD"=>"can be left blank","AED"=>" and amount processed on order"),
              );

        function filterData(&$str)
        {
            $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
            $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
            if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
        }

        // file name for download
        $fileName = "codexworld_export_data" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

        // headers for download




        $flag = false;
        foreach($data as $row) {
            if(!$flag) {
                // display column names as first row
             echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
                $flag = true;
            }
            // filter data
      array_walk($row, 'filterData');
               $rows=  implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"  . implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";


            file_put_contents( $fileName, $rows);
        }

        exit;
    ?>
```

The file on opencart is located in: public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php

Probably I need to integrate the code of creating an excel on part of the file where it sends an email about order to store owner to have the same contents.

Order.php code: http://ideone.com/pYcR18

Comment: the code sample in that link has some godawful formatting. Clear it up so that its easier to read.

Comment: @takarii I need to find in that file where to integrate the code that will create excel file

Comment: @shadyyx can you help me with this please.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that was much easier than I was expected. 
Since nobody paid attention, I spent a couple of hours researching and found solution. So if somebody needs to generate an excel file that have to be sent to delivery company, here it is:

Open whether public_html/system/storage/modification/catalog/model/checkout/order.php

or public_html/catalog/model/checkout/order.php cause for some people 2nd link worked but for me 1st link worked.

Search for this:

```
// Admin Alert Mail
```

then scroll down till this:

```
$mail = new Mail();
                $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/order', $data));
                $mail->setText($text);
                $mail->send();
```

Paste this code to generate the excel file:

```
//excel

                         $data2 = array(
        array("ORDER ID" => $order_id, "COMPANY NAME" => "Your company name", "ADDRESS LINE1" =>$data['shipping_address'], "ADDRESS LINE2" => $data['shipping_address_2'],"CONTACT PERSON"=>$order_info['shipping_firstname']." ".$order_info['shipping_lastname'],"CITY" =>$order_info['shipping_city'], "PHONE_1"=>$data['telephone'],"CONTENT" =>"", "WH NUMBER" =>$product['model'],"PIECES"=>$product['quantity'],"COD"=>"","Total"=>$order_info['total']),
          );

    function filterData(&$str)
    {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }

    // file name for download
    $fileName = $order_id.".xls";



    $flag = false;
    foreach($data2 as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
            // display column names as first row
         echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        // filter data
  array_walk($row, 'filterData');
           $rows=  implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n"  . implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";


        file_put_contents( $fileName, $rows);
    }

$mail->setTo('email of delivery company or any you need');
                $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setHtml($this->load->view('mail/excel', $data));
                $mail->setText($text);
                $mail->send();
```

Go to public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/ and create a file excel.tpl.

Paste this to excel.tpl:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
<div style="width: 680px;"><a href="<?php echo $store_url; ?>" title="<?php echo $store_name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $store_name; ?>" style="margin-bottom: 20px; border: none;" /></a>



Find and order in excel file here:

<a href="http://yourwebsiteurl.com/<?php echo $order_id; ?>.xls">Download</a>

  <?php if ($customer_id) { ?>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_link; ?></p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a></p>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php if ($download) { ?>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_download; ?></p>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><a href="<?php echo $download; ?>"><?php echo $download; ?></a></p>
  <?php } ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;" colspan="2"><?php echo $text_order_detail; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_order_id; ?></b> <?php echo $order_id; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_date_added; ?></b> <?php echo $date_added; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_payment_method; ?></b> <?php echo $payment_method; ?><br />
          <?php if ($shipping_method) { ?>
          <b><?php echo $text_shipping_method; ?></b> <?php echo $shipping_method; ?>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><b><?php echo $text_email; ?></b> <?php echo $email; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_telephone; ?></b> <?php echo $telephone; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_ip; ?></b> <?php echo $ip; ?><br />
          <b><?php echo $text_order_status; ?></b> <?php echo $order_status; ?><br /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php if ($comment) { ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_instruction; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $comment; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <?php } ?>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_payment_address; ?></td>
        <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_shipping_address; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $payment_address; ?></td>
        <?php if ($shipping_address) { ?>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $shipping_address; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_product; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: left; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_model; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_quantity; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_price; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; background-color: #EFEFEF; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding: 7px; color: #222222;"><?php echo $text_total; ?></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['name']; ?>
          <?php foreach ($product['option'] as $option) { ?>
          <br />
          &nbsp;<small> - <?php echo $option['name']; ?>: <?php echo $option['value']; ?></small>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['model']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $product['total']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php foreach ($vouchers as $voucher) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['description']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: left; padding: 7px;"></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;">1</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $voucher['amount']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><?php echo $text_footer; ?></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now try to order something from a web site and it should work.